# how do i populate another control from the value of another in Xforms?

Tags: xforms

I am currently developing an archive system with XForms and am a beginner. I have two forms and they have a common field that needs to be populated with the same value i.e the value of the second form's field depends on the value entered in the first form. I want this entry to be done automatically, when I fill the first form then I don't have to enter that value again in the second form. Since I am saving to a MySQL database, I need both fields to populate their corresponding tables in the database. How would you do this?

Comment: your questions seems to imply that fields are in different forms, i.e. not visible at the screen at the same time. If that isn't the case, see @Phil's answer (http://goo.gl/YMcTe). But if you want to pre-populate a field with a value entered by users previously in another form, I'd suggest you create a service that returns that value, call this service on `xforms-model-construct-done`, and use `xforms:setvalue` to populate the field based on the returned value.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [the setvalue action](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms11#action-setvalue) and the [xforms-value-changed](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms11#evt-valueChanged) event:

```
<xf:input bind="foo">
    <xf:label>First control:</xf:label>
    <xf:setvalue ev:event="xforms-value-changed" bind="bar" value="context()" />
</xf:input>

<xf:input bind="bar">
    <xf:label>Second control:</xf:label>
    <xf:setvalue ev:event="xforms-value-changed" bind="foo" value="context()" />
</xf:input>
```

Alternatively, you could use [the calculate attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms11#model-prop-calculate) on [the bind element](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms11#structure-bind-element):

```
<xf:bind nodeset="instance('bar')/slave" calculate="instance('foo')/master" />
```

Note that this second approach would have the effect of making the control(s) that bind to the node read-only, which may not be your intention.

**EDIT:** Looks like I completely misunderstood your question. Ignore me, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you have two options to create such a workflow: Using the FormBuilder/ FormRunner (but since i don't use them, i can't help you with those), or "by hand" using  [XML pipelines](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xml-pipeline-language-xpl) and e.g. the [SQL Processor](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/processors-sql) to interact with SQL databases.

- **[XML pipelines (XPL)](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/xml-pipeline-language-xpl)** let you process XML data, for example creating chunks of XML based on [session data](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/processors-request-generator), [XML](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/processors-xml-databases) or [SQL](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/processors-sql) databases or [XML web services](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/processors-xforms-submission). XPL is similar to XProc, but gives access to additional modules called processors:
- **Processors**, for example the [SQL processor](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/processors-sql), provide an "interface" to interact with SQL databases, making available the full range of SQL CRUD operations.

If both forms you're talking of are part the same `xforms:model`, you can connect them using the technique described by Phil.

If they aren't, you will need to make the `xforms:instance` data of form 1 persistent before navigating to form 2. Usually, `xforms:submission`s are used to send data to the persistence layer. You will have to create the following elements:

- a `xforms:submission` element inside the xforms:model of form 1, sending the instance data to a certain xpl pipeline (called xpl 1);
- xpl 1 to write the data to the sql database: at least a sql processor component is needed to build and send the required sql command. you could add a xslt processor if you need to preprocess the instance data.
- xpl 2 to read from the sql database: same as xpl 1, just the other way. Splitting the read operation (xpl 2) from writing to the sql db (xpl 1) has the advantage of higher flexibility, making form 2 more independent from form 1.
- in your form 2, you can initialize the instance using xpl 2. There are [different ways to initialize the `xforms:instance` described in the Wiki](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/how-to/logic/load-initial-form-data).

Using those components, you can create very flexible workflows.